# How to edit the ASP.NET HTML Body variable?

Tags: string, asp-classic

```
body = "<HTML>" & _
 "<HEAD></HEAD>" & _
 "<BODY>" & _
 " <Font Face=Arial Size=5><B>" & _
 "  This is a test Email" & cEmail & _
 " </B></Font><BR>" & _
 " <H3><A Href=http://www.website.com>Click here</a>" & _
 " to go to website.com</h3>" & _
 "</BODY>" & _
 "</HTML>"
```

this a ASP variable with html text it works well i just want to know how would i be able to implement the `img src=""` tag on there using a variable so something like this 
`img src="http:www" & website &".com"` any ideas? thanks

Comment: No idea what you want to do here.  You are setting a variable named body to some html... then what?  Is it being sent in an email?  What do you want to change?  Can you show the code with the variable you want to use?  The example you gave in bold looks like it would work fine.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: yes trying to embed an image. this body variable is used to send on an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you're asking how to concatenate in ASP classic. Assumming the variable:

```
Website = "example"
```

You concatenate by doing:

```
body = "<a href=""http://www." & Website & """><img src=""http://www." & Website & """ /></a>"
```

Comment: Thanks this was the answer to my problem!